# Need help on creating a conditional statement in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

Can anyone tell me what's wrong about this pandas conditional statement?
​

```
dfm_Final['Pass'] = np.where(
    dfm_Final['Percent_change'] >= 0.8 * dfm_Final['Agg_Percent_change'] &
    dfm_Final['Percent_change'] <= 1.25 * dfm_Final['Agg_Percent_change'], True, False)
```

I'm trying  to create a new column called 'Pass' based on the the condition that the 'Percent_change' Column value is 'pass' if it falls between 80% and 125% of the 'Agg_percent_change' value and 'fail' otherwise. Thank you.

[image: This is what I want to achieve.]

Comment: You don't need to use `np.where`. Your long condition would return a true-false column regardless.

Comment: As an aside, `True` could be `'Pass'` and `False` could be `'Fail'` instead of postprocessing later.

Comment: Missing parenthesis is the issue: `(dfm_Final['Percent_change'] >= (0.8 * dfm_Final['Agg_Percent_change'])) & (dfm_Final['Percent_change'] <= (1.25 * dfm_Final['Agg_Percent_change']))` Each condition needs to be in parenthesis as `&` has precedence. the pattern needs to be -> `(full condition 1) & (full condition 2)...`

Comment: Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

like mentioned in comment, you don't need np.where, also use `()`

```
dfm_Final['Pass'] = 
    (dfm_Final['Percent_change'] >= 0.8 * dfm_Final['Agg_Percent_change']) &
    (dfm_Final['Percent_change'] <= 1.25 * dfm_Final['Agg_Percent_change'])
```